# How to move Legacy SQL request into standard SQL with nested fields in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have very simple legacy SQL construction like this

```js
SELECT
  report_date,
  campaign.bundleId,
  campaign.countryCode,
  campaign.stageNum
FROM
  [...records_20200708],
  [...records_20200707]
```

I'm tried to convert it into Standard SQL

```js
SELECT
  report_date,
  (select bundleId from unnest(campaign)) as campaign_bundleId,
  (select countryCode from unnest(campaign)) as campaign_countryCode,
  (select stageNum from unnest(campaign)) as campaign_stageNum

FROM
  `...records_*`
```

It does not work. I'm getting an error: `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`.
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: please clarify - what is the data type of `campaign` column? is it `repeated record` or `record` or anything else?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you for reply. `campaign` is repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL to address that error message you are getting `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` - just add `ARRAY` so BQ knows how to handle those `more than one element` in output

```
SELECT
  report_date,
  ARRAY(SELECT bundleId FROM UNNEST(campaign)) AS campaign_bundleId,
  ARRAY(SELECT countryCode FROM UNNEST(campaign)) AS campaign_countryCode,
  ARRAY(SELECT stageNum FROM UNNEST(campaign)) AS campaign_stageNum

FROM
  `...records_*`
```

Or, depends on expected output - you can use below

```
SELECT
  report_date,
  c.bundleId AS campaign_bundleId,
  c.countryCode AS campaign_countryCode,
  c.stageNum AS campaign_stageNum

FROM
  `...records_*`,
UNNEST(campaign) AS c
```